# Email php not showing in certain formats! help!

Tags: php, email

I am trying to set up a newsletter system. I have taken the coding from codecanyon.net and have amended the newsletter templates etc.

You get the option to then send a preview, php results show up in all the formats I have checked (i.e. hotmail) however some do not show the CSS styling.

However, when it runs as a cron job, the php raw coding shows and nothing else.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: need to see actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Whether your email gets rendered correctly using the styling you put in the HTML **depends entirely** on the email client. So even if you have a perfectly styled html, the clients might just refuse to show the html and instead render it in plain text.

Comment: its more the php coding thats confusing me, its just showing the coding when i dont send in preview mode!

Comment: How does your cronjob line looks like?